# Why does assigning 0xFFFFFFFF to a UInteger generate an error in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, types

A UInteger data type holds any value between 0 and 4,294,967,295 (ref. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x79h55x9.aspx)).

If I try this code in VB.NET, I get a compiler error:

```
Dim Test As UInteger = &HFFFFFFFF
```

> Error: "Constant expression not representable in type 'UInteger'.

Why I can't set 0xFFFFFFFF (4,294,967,295) to a UInteger if this type can hold this value?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe it's because the literal `&HFFFFFFFF` is interpreted by the VB.NET compiler as an `Integer`, and that value for an `Integer` is a negative number (-1), which obviously can't be cast to a `UInteger`.

This issue is easily fixed by writing `&HFFFFFFFFUI`, appending the `UI` suffix to treat the literal as a `UInteger`.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32.maxvalue.aspx) constant:

```
Dim Test As UInteger = UInteger.MaxValue
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/2d9fd669-a94b-46de-b832-e5d05ab9d803), it appears the solution is to set the value as **&HFFFFFFFFUI**, since according the article:

> If you just write &HFFFFFFFF then it is treated as a signed 32 bit integer, value is -1, and you can't assign that to a UInteger.
>
> If you write &HFFFFFFFFL then it is treated as a signed 64 bit integer, now the binary is:
> 0000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111

Comment: The correct suffix for `UInteger` would be `UI` or `ui`, so in this example `&HFFFFFFFFui` should be preferred to `L` because with `L` a narrowing conversion is required.

Comment: Great insight. I updated the bold part accordingly. The article (forum) was a few years old.

Comment: This answer doesn't really make sense any more. You quote and cite an article, in support of a completely different solution that came from a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, it's worth nothing that "LongValue = LongValue And Not &h8000" just clears one bit in 'LongValue', as does "LongValue = LongValue And Not &h800000000000".  On the other hand, "LongValue = LongValue And Not &h80000000" will clear out the top 33 bits of LongValue.

Answer (score -1):

You can write "-1" which is the same as 4,294,967,295